# How to convert a ISO8601 UTC date string to Swift Date?

Tags: swift, date, datetime, utc

Please read through the comments, I have addded my question is the comment to make it easier to understand my confusion. Appreciate your help.
My confusion is I use the first method to covert a string ISO8601 formatted UTC date to a Swift Date object. This give me the right date and time as per the current time zone. However when I pass that result to the next method to format it I get it an incorrect result unless I specificy the timezone as UTC. This is confuses me because the first method converts the date to the current time zone. Or am I missing something here because I feel like I am?

```
//The date that was sent to the server was AEDT March 14th 10:00 AM
//It was converted to UTC by doing this
/**
 let isoDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
 isoDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
 self.date = isoDateFormatter.string(from: data.date)
 */

//formatter used 
private let isoDateFormatter: ISO8601DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    return formatter
}()

//These Test Inputs are in UTC ISO8601 Formats
//I'm running this in my Playground
let dateString = "2023-03-13T23:00:00.000Z"
let dateString2 = "2023-03-13T23:00:00.000+00:00"

func dateFromUTCString(_ dateString: String) -> Date? {
    guard let date = isoDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    else {
        return nil
    }
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let localOffset = calendar.timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: date)
    let localDate = Date(timeInterval: TimeInterval(localOffset), since: date)
    //I get the right local date, issue is when I format it in the next method 
    return localDate
}

func formattedDate(from date: Date?) -> String {
    guard let date = date else {return "no date"}
    let f = DateFormatter()
    //f.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    f.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy 'at' h:mm a"
    return f.string(from: date)
    //after applying the formatting I get 14 Mar 2023 at 9:00 PM but it should 14 Mar 2023 at 10:00 AM
    //I can only get the right date formatted if i set f.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC").
    //That part doesn't make sense to me.Because the date passed into this method is in the current time zone. 
//This was converted to current time zone in the previous method isn't it?
}
```

Comment: Why does `dateFromUTCString` do all of the strange (and unnecessary) conversion to `localDate`? You should simply return `date` and be done. You should also remove the setting of the timezone on the date formatter. The date strings you parse specify their own timezone.

Comment: @HangarRash I tried doing it without using all the strange things but I end up getting the date and time in UTC. Would you be able to take this input - 
```2023-03-13T23:00:00.000Z``` and confirm that you can get 2023-03-14 10:00:00 +0000 as swift date as a result? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your confusion probably stem from your misunderstanding of `Date` and its formating, see: 
 [Apple Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date)
 A `Date` is `A specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone`.
 It is only when you format it into a string that it is displayed
 in the TimeZone you have selected.
 
 So your statements, `...first method converts the date to the current time zone.` and
 `This was converted to current time zone in the previous method isn't it?`
 are not correct, no `Date` is converted, it is only displayed.

Comment: @MinonWeerasinghe But that would be incorrect. The string `2023-03-13T23:00:00.000Z` should give you a resulting date of `2023-03-13 23:00:00 +0000`. If you are in the UTC+11 timezone then that is the same as `2023-03-14 10:00:00 +1100`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thats very helpful. I think for some reason I thought I can "change time". In the implemenation, I should format and preset the date in the current timezone but that doesn't and shouldn't change the original Date object.